# Downloading .sh files through Terminal

Tags: linux, curl, terminal, wget, conda

I am looking for a way to download https://www.anaconda.com/download/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh through terminal; now don't laugh just yet, there are some provisos.

I don't have root privileges.

```
 $wget https://www.anaconda.com/download/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

does not work because this will not download the .sh file it will download an HTML that will cause issues with running it in bash.

I have also tried

```
 $curl -o Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh https://www.anaconda.com/download/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and it does not work; it produces this output

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

and

```
$curl https://www.anaconda.com/download/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

which produces no output.

Overall I have no idea where to go from here and I was wondering if any of you had some ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that link is a 404 :/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use instead:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

the `https://www.anaconda.com/download/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` is not the repo

Comment: Have to wait one more minute

Answer (score 2):

This is the URL from the Anaconda [website](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux).

Try this
`wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

**READ** the script, then pass it to bash. Even if it is from a trusted source always read `.sh` scripts you download before executing them with your shell.